# Why is Safari slow at updating element positions?

Tags: javascript, css, safari

I noticed that Safari is way slower at updating CSS element positions when they are changed in javascript.

For instance, we can fix an element's position to scrolling in 2 ways: via javascript and via the `position: fixed` CSS value, as illustrated in this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/76tnuwmp/4/

In browsers like Chrome and Firefox, the user can't visibly see a difference in the 2 methods while scrolling.

However, in Safari, users can visibly see the lag in updating for the box fixed with javascript.

Is there something fundamentally different about how Safari updates element positions? Does it perhaps perform compositing and layering at a slower rate than other browsers do? Or is it just slow at one or more of these steps?

Comment: I think safari updates JS at a slower rate than the 60fps that Chrome and Firefox aim for. Not sure why that is, maybe they're trying to conserve CPU usage and battery.

Comment: How do you know that?